# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map') while mount component in next js

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, next.js

I have these configurations in my products component:

```
import axios from "axios";
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import productsAction from "../redux/actions/productsAction";
import { FETCH_PRODUCTS } from "../redux/actions/types";

function products({ products }) {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("http://localhost:8197/Plant/GetPlant").then(({ data }) =>
      dispatch({
        type: FETCH_PRODUCTS,
        payload: data,
      })
    );
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {products.map((product, index) => (
        <h1 key={index}>{product.title}</h1>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    products: state.products.products,
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(products);
```

Everything is okay, but when I run the project, It throws an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
```

And when I inspect the project by redux devtools, the products array is equal to [].

How can I fix error?

Comment: what does your `axios` request do ?

Comment: Fetching an initial data

Comment: does any of the two answers solve your problem?

Comment: Yes it does but i was lookuping for a better way

Comment: I can provide a better solution if you want?

Comment: Yeah I would tnx and congratulation.

Comment: I've submitted my answer please check it out.

Comment: Did it work for you ?

Comment: It works. but I was looking for an alternative to conditional rendering.

Answer (score 2):

The most efficient way do this is to add a `loading state` and a `loader`. When `axios` is sending a request set the `loading state` to `true` and when the data is received set it back to `false`.

And while the `loading state` is `true` show a `loader` on your page.

```
const Products = () => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true) // <------Set loading state to true------>
    axios.get("http://localhost:8197/Plant/GetPlant").then(({ data }) =>
      dispatch({
        type: FETCH_PRODUCTS,
        payload: data,
      })
    );
   setLoading(false) // <---------Set loading state to false after data is retreived------->
  }, []);

  if(loading) {
    return <p>Loading...</p> // <-----Return a loading component which shows a loader when loading state is true
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {products && products.map((product, index) => (
        <h1 key={index}>{product.title}</h1>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

your code is accessing products before it is initialized. What you could do now is conditional rendering.

```js
<div>
    {products && products.map((product, index) => (
        <h1 key={index}>{product.title}</h1>
    ))}
</div>
```

Comment: Why does it happened or why mapStateToProps run after products.map?  Does serverSideProps is an alternative way to prevent error?

Comment: you have a useEffect which makes an api call. API calls runs in the background and elements are meanwhile rendered. You're referring to the props values before the prop values is populated. Your api call finishes after the page is rendered. and your error occurs while rendering because the api call hasn't finished yet and there are no products populated

Answer (score 1):

You are rendering the products before the API call which will definitely return undefined.

So instead write

```
{
 products?.map((product, index) => (
        <h1 key={index}>{product.title}</h1>
      ))
}
```

or

```
{
!!products && products.map((product, index) => (
        <h1 key={index}>{product.title}</h1>
      ))
}
```

Comment: Why does it happened or why mapStateToProps run after products.map?  Does serverSideProps is an alternative way to prevent error?